# How to find set intersection of sets between the documents in a single collection in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

The below collection named "coll" was maintained in the mongodb.

```
{
    {"_id":1, "set":[1,2,3,4,5]},
    {"_id":2, "set":[0,2,6,4,5]},
    {"_id":3, "set":[1,2,5,10,22]}
}
```

How to find the intersection of the set elements in the above collection documents with `_id`'s 1 and 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the **[aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** to get the desired result. The aggregation **[set operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-set/)** that would do the magic is **[`$setIntersection`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/)**.

The following aggregation pipeline achieves what you are after:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": { "$in": [1, 3] }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "set1": { "$first": "$set" },
            "set2": { "$last": "$set" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": { 
            "set1": 1, 
            "set2": 1, 
            "commonToBoth": { "$setIntersection": [ "$set1", "$set2" ] }, 
            "_id": 0 
        }
    }
])
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "set1" : [1,2,3,4,5],
            "set2" : [1,2,5,10,22],
            "commonToBoth" : [1,2,5]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

---

### UPDATE

For three or more documents to be intersected, you'd need the **[`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce)** operator to flatten the arrays. This will allow you to intersect any number of arrays, so instead of just doing an intersection of the two arrays from docs 1 and 3, this will apply to multiple arrays as well.

Consider running the following aggregate operation:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "_id": { "$in": [1, 3] } } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "sets": { "$push": "$set" },
            "initialSet": { "$first": "$set" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "commonSets": {
                "$reduce": {
                    "input": "$sets",
                    "initialValue": "$initialSet",
                    "in": { "$setIntersection": ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Can u explain whats happening in the group stage of the pipeline and how to proceed if we wanna perform intersection across three or four documents in a collection

Comment: This will only work if there are *exactly two* documents to be intersected. If there are three or more, it will not work (because you can no longer use $first and $last to project the arrays separately).

Comment: Congratulations for the response! But i have the following problem: Since i want to intersect all documents i get `BufBuilder attempted to grow() to 67108870 bytes, past the 64MB limit.` because my sets are extremely high: every set may contains around 600K elements of 7 bytes. Do you have a solution or workaround to propose? Thank you in advance!