# Mongo intersection measure select

Tags: mongodb

I have the following documents:

```
{'variations': ['BlueViolet', 'CadetBlue', 'Cyan']}
{'variations': ['LightPink', 'VioletRed']}
```

And I want to write a query that selects all documents where size of intersection between variations field and  `{'Cyan', 'CadetBlue', 'SmoothsRed'}` is greater than 2.

Can this be performed with mongodb operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link explains how to achieve what you want - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIntersection/
In order to write the comparison, I'll have to assume each document can be uniquely identified using an _id value, and then you can write your query using the solution given in this answer - [How to find set intersection of sets between the documents in a single collection in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646534/how-to-find-set-intersection-of-sets-between-the-documents-in-a-single-collectio)

Good luck