# How to get common array elements mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework

First document:

```
    {
    "_id" : 1,
    "array" : [ 
        {
            "userID" : 1,
            "name" : "name 1"
        }, 
        {
            "userID" : 2,
            "name" : "name 2"
        }, 
        {
            "userID" : 3,
            "name" : "name 3"
        }, 
        {
            "userID" : 6,
            "name" : "name 6"
        }
    ]
}
```

Second document:

```
    {
    "_id" : 2,
    "array" : [ 
        {
            "userID" : 1,
            "name" : "name 1"
        }, 
        {
            "userID" : 2,
            "name" : "name 2"
        }, 
        {
            "userID" : 3,
            "name" : "name 3"
        }, 
        {
            "userID" : 4,
            "name" : "name 4"
        }, 
        {
            "userID" : 5,
            "name" : "name 5"
        }
    ]
}
```

is there any way to get output like this:

```
   {    
    "array" : [  
        {  
            "userID" : 1,  
            "name" : "name 1" 
        },  
        {  
            "userID" : 2,  
            "name" : "name 2"  
        },   
        {  
            "userID" : 3,  
            "name" : "name 3"  
        }  
    ]  

    }
```

I want to compare array fields of two documents and retrieve common elements in it. And compare array fields only by common `'userID'`. Can we do it by `$setIntersection`? I need to check only two array fields at a time.

Comment: Will there always be 2 documents ? and is this (the 2 documents) an aggregation result ?

Comment: it is not an aggregation result. and i will take two documents by document._id

Comment: by `First Document` and `Secoend Document` do you mean, this are different different Objects right? or part of a SIngle Object?

Comment: you could also look into this answer , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646534/how-to-find-set-intersection-of-sets-between-the-documents-in-a-single-collectio?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: yes by first document and second document, these are two different objects

Comment: i want to compare array fields by userID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$setIntersection`

```
db.t67.aggregate([
    //{$match : {}} add filter criteria to filter documents
    {$group : {_id : null, array : {$push : "$array"}}},
    {$project : {_id :0, array : {$reduce : {input : "$array", initialValue : {$arrayElemAt : ["$array", 0]}, in : {$setIntersection : ["$$this", "$$value"]}}}}}
])
```

output

```
> db.t67.aggregate([
...     {$group : {_id : null, array : {$push : "$array"}}},
... {$project : {_id :0, array : {$reduce : {input : "$array", initialValue : {$arrayElemAt : ["$array", 0]}, in : {$setIntersection : ["$$this", "$$value"]}}}}}
... ])
{ "array" : [ { "userID" : 1, "name" : "name 1" }, { "userID" : 2, "name" : "name 2" }, { "userID" : 3, "name" : "name 3" } ] }
```

or `$unwind` and `$group`

```
db.t67.aggregate([
    // $match stages to filter 2 documents
    {$unwind : "$array"},
    {$group : {_id : "$array", count : {$sum : 1}}},
    {$match : {count : {$gt : 1}}},
    {$project : {count : 0}},
    {$group : {_id : null, array : {$push : "$_id"}}},
    {$project : {_id : 0}}
])
```

output

```
{ "_id" : null, "array" : [ { "userID" : 3, "name" : "name 3" }, { "userID" : 2, "name" : "name 2" }, { "userID" : 1, "name" : "name 1" } ] }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.here we unwind array field of all documents, right? my collection has lot of documents like this. so i want to take only particular documents. not all documents. i can't take particular documents by passing document id from this query.

Comment: you need to add `$match` stage to filter the documents, in the answer I have commented the $match stage where you need to specify the filter criteria