# How can I do a intersection betwen several arrays?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am retrieving the following data:

```
[
    {
        "_id": null,
        "count": 2,
        "students": [
            [
                "a",
                "b"
            ],
            [
                "a",
                "c",
                "d"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

Using this query:

```
aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        class: {
          $in: classes,
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: { students: 1 },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        data: { $push: "$students" },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        count: 1,
        students: {
          $setIntersection: "$data",
        },
      },
    },
])
```

But the idea is that students become at an intersection of that arrays in order to get only

```
[
    {
        "_id": null,
        "count": 2,
        "students": [
            [
                "a",
            ],
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried several combinations of using `setIntersection` but none of them worked.

How can get only that intersection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiple arrays intersection concept is similar to [chridam's answer on How to find set intersection of sets between the documents in a single collection in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30646856/8017690).

1. `$unwind`: Deconstruct `students` array field to output documents for each element.
2. `group`: Group multiple documents to get `initialStudent` (`$first`).
3. `$set`: Create new field `common`. With `$reduce` operator to flatten the array for `$setIntersection` start from `initialStudent` and every next element in `$students`.
4. `$project`: Display `student` field with a nested array for the result of `common` in (3).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$students"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": 0,
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      "students": {
        "$push": "$students"
      },
      "initialStudent": {
        "$first": "$students"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "common": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$students",
          "initialValue": "$initialStudent",
          "in": {
            "$setIntersection": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "count": 1,
      "students": [
        "$common"
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EiJH5rucmm2)

---

### Improvement

Appreciate and credit @varman's suggestion on the query,

Pipelines 1 (`$unwind`) & 2 (`$group`) for the above solution can be simplified into `$set` pipeline to retrieve `$first` and `$count` for `students`.

```
{
  $addFields: {
    "initialStudent": {
      "$first": "$students"
    },
    "count": {
      "$size": "$students"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is great. A small improvement I can give is https://mongoplayground.net/p/dwFUuBwAo6S . We do reduce the use of `$unwind` then `$group` since both are expensive.

Comment: Hi @varman, thanks for your suggestion. And yes, your query looks more simple/shorten and better on the performance. Really appreciate the lesson provided. =)

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to do the intersection after getting the data.

```
//assuming students has only two arrays.
const IntersectedArray = students[0].filter(value => students[1].includes(value));
```

Comment: can have several arrays not only two, any way thanks